Blazor Server - KeyCloak Logout - Missing parameters: id_token_hint
I have a Blazor Server web app (.Net 9) integrated with KeyCloak (V26) for authentication. Application authentication flow:

Un-authorized access (Role auhtorization) or Click Login, redirects to KeyCloak login page.
On successful login KeyCloak redirects to the main Blazor App.

For Logout, expected behavior is to redirect to KeyCloak, initiate logout and redirect back to Blazor app home page. Instead, on Logout the Blazor App redirects to KeyCloak and I get the "Missing parameters: id_token_hint" error.
Blazor App - Logout code:
@page "/logout"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject IConfiguration Configuration

<PageTitle>Log Out</PageTitle>


@code {

    [CascadingParameter]
    private HttpContext HttpContext { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        if (HttpMethods.IsGet(HttpContext.Request.Method))
        {
            
            // sign-out from the default authentication scheme
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new AuthenticationProperties
                {                    
                   RedirectUri = "/"
                });

            // sign-out from the cookie authentication scheme
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        }
    }
}

KeyCloak - Logout Error

Based on my investigation either Client Id or Id_Token_Hint needs to be passed in the logout URI. I manually (in the browser) added Client Id in the logout URI query string, and it gave an option to click Logout, which I did not like. How to get and set the Id_Token_Hint, so the logout happens and gets redirected to Blazor app home page? Please help.

If you use the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect will need to enable SaveTokens.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(...)
    .AddCookie()
    .AddOpenIdConnect(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
    {
        ...
        options.SaveTokens = true;   //important  to get idtoken      or will report missing id_token_hint
    });



As explained by Qiang Fu, the simple way is to save the idtoken in your OpenIdConnect config and the signout will work.
I don't like that you cannot choose to only keep the idtoken and don't have an option to avoid saving the access token in the base options of .AddOpenIdConnect extension.
To avoid that, I implements something like that.
.AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
{
    {
        //input standard options here and don't save all the token
        options.SaveTokens = false;

        options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
        {
            OnTokenValidated = async x =>
            {
                //code here if you want to store you token in cache server side
            },
            OnTokenResponseReceived = async x =>
            {
                //Only store id_token in cookie 
                x.Properties!.StoreTokens([ new AuthenticationToken
                    {
                        Name = "id_token",
                        Value = x.TokenEndpointResponse.IdToken
                    }]);

                await Task.CompletedTask;
            },
        };
    }
}

